# JavaFX: my tooltip is not showing up and I'm not sure why

Tags: java, javafx, graphics, tooltip

I want to add a tooltip to a TableColumn but for some reason, it is not showing up even though it seems as if my implementation is correct. What is wrong with my implementation. I got the tooltip to show up once after my mouse was on the spot for 3 minutes but how can I get the tooltip to show immediately instead of waiting a long time for a long while?
[image]

```
    //Name Column
        TableColumn<AuctionItem, String> itemNameCol = new TableColumn<>();
        Label nameLabel = new Label("Items");
        nameLabel.setTooltip(new Tooltip("This gives the name of the product"));
        itemNameCol.setGraphic(nameLabel);
```

Comment: It seems to work for me.  What version of JavaFX are you using?  On what operating system are you running?

Comment: The newest version of JavaFX on Windows 11

Comment: [mcve] please.. anyway, this is a hack that was needed in the past - why don't you go for the clean solution suggested in my comment to your previous (same requirement) question?